# How to code exception in stored proc that will work with Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, exception

I have a SQL Server proc that returns a result set. I have validation logic that throws an exception in the TRY. The CATCH reTHROWS the exception to the caller. The problem is EF won't create the complex type for me unless I explicitly add a SELECT of the result set to the CATCH. That's fine and good but now my reTHROW doesn't work. If I put the SELECT of the result after the reTHROW the exception gets rethrown but EF won't create the complex type. How do I get EF to recognize the result set structure (to create the complex type in my model) and reTHROW the exception back to the caller?

Here's a watered down version of the proc to make it more readable...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test (@as_opt varchar(10))
AS

/* Force EF to execute proc */
set fmtonly off

declare @ls_msg nvarchar(2048)

create table #results
   (
   code_type             varchar(10),
   descr                 varchar(80)
   )

BEGIN TRY       
    IF @as_opt is null
    begin
                          select @ls_msg = 'Option is null';
        THROW 51000, @ls_msg, 1
    end

    /* populate temp table with some dummy data */
    insert #results (code_type, descr)
    select 'TYPE1','Type 1 Description'
    union
    select 'TYPE2','Type 2 Description'

    /* return result set */     
    select code_type, descr from #results   
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    /* So EF will know what result looks like */
    select top 1 code_type, descr from #results;

    /* Rethrow the exception to the caller so they can handle it */     
    THROW 51000, @ls_msg, 1
END CATCH
go
```

Thanks for all help,
Mark

VS2012
SQL Server 2012
EF6

Answer (score 0):

If the Exception from Entity Framework is an `SqlException` then you can retrive your error code through the `ErrorCode` property on the `SqlException`.

You will be able to see your error code 51000 and then do whatever you need to do to alert the user/deal with this.

Comment: My apologies I seem to have misunderstood the question.

Comment: I don't think there is a way for this to be done. Can you not validate the parameter before sending it to the procedure?

Comment: Yes I certainly can and will but I work in a shop with several people and one of them may decide to use the proc for another system. I'm just trying to cover my bases.

Comment: In that case your error message will be useful. I guess in the EF code you will have to detect this. Likewise other users of the sproc will encounter this error when they try to input the parameter as null - they would also have to handle this error in their calling code.

Comment: Handling the error is fine but that still leaves the problem of EF creating the complex type. When I add the proc to model EF executes the proc with null parameters which causes the exception to be thrown in the proc. Since the THROW is before the SELECT EF doesn't know how to handle it and doesn't create the complex type.

Comment: What are the steps that lead to this problem? Are you using the EF model designer to add and map this procedure?

Comment: Right click on the EF model design surface. Selected Update model from database. On the Add tab drill down and select the proc I want to add. This results in the proc getting added to the model store, getting added as a function import, getting a new complex type called [proc name]_Result. The last part doesn't isn't happening. I' given up for now and commented out my logic that validates the proc arguments. This way when EF runs the proc to add it to the model it won't fail validation and end up in the CATCH. Since the CATCH won't execute during the load I don't need the SELECT in it either.